# Анимация на jQuery

Tags: jquery, анимация

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как можно задать задержку в начале перед ее выполнением?  Пытался так но не помогает? Подскажите, пожалуйста?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function myFunction () {
$("#top").animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000);
setTimeout("myFunction()", 5000);
};
});
```

Comment: Какая версия jQuery?

Comment: Имеется ввиду задержка функции перед ее начальным выполнение.

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min

Comment: Нужна версия max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если версия jQuery > 1.4, то

```
$("#top").delay(5000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000);
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось! Скажите, а чем min версия отличается от max?

Comment: min версия пожата, удалены комментарии и лишние пробелы.